# UVa 10035 Primary Arithmetic

Tags: c++

Can anybody tell me why my program keeps getting wrong answer? It must count the number of carry operations in a sum.
I tried every testcase came to my mind. I didn't get wrong output.

#### Problem Description:

Children are taught to add multi-digit numbers from right-to-left one digit at a time. Many find the "carry" operation - in which a 1 is carried from one digit position to be added to the next - to be a significant challenge. Your job is to count the number of carry operations for each of a set of addition problems so that educators may assess their difficulty.

#### Input

Each line of input contains two unsigned integers less than 10 digits. The last line of input contains 0 0.

#### Output

For each line of input except the last you should compute and print the number of carry operations that would result from adding the two numbers, in the format shown below.

#### Sample Input

```
123 456
555 555
123 594
0 0
```

#### Sample Output

```
No carry operation.
3 carry operations.
1 carry operation.
```

Here's my current code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

unsigned long a, b, carry;
vector <int> v1, v2;
int index_a, index_b;

void digit(unsigned long x, unsigned long y)
{
    for(int i=x; i>0; i/=10)
        v1.push_back(i%10);
    for(int i=y; i>0; i/=10)
        v2.push_back(i%10);
}

int main()
{
    while(cin>>a>>b && a!=0 && b!=0)
    {
        v1.clear();
        v2.clear();
        int carry_counter=0;
        digit(a, b);

        for(int j=0; j<v1.size() && j<v2.size(); j++)
        {
            carry=(v1[j]+v2[j]+carry)/10;
            if(carry)
                carry_counter++;
            index_a=index_b=j;
        }

        for(int i=index_a; i+1<v1.size(); i++)
        {
            carry=(v1[i]+carry)/10; 
            if(carry)
                carry_counter++;
        }

        for(int i=index_b; i+1<v2.size(); i++)
        {
            carry=(v2[i]+carry)/10;
            if(carry)
                carry_counter++;
        }

        if(carry_counter==1)
            cout<<"1 carry operation."<<endl;
        else if(carry_counter>1)
            cout<<carry_counter<<" carry operations."<<endl;
        else
            cout<<"No carry operation."<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: step through in debugger...

Comment: Did so. Didn't find anything wrong.

Comment: Try adding a new test case for the input that fails. I am concerned that most of your logic is inside main, so I'm not sure how you will test it.

Comment: Did you know that you can read integers as strings, when you only need their digits?!?!

Comment: First you say "Can anybody tell me why my program keeps getting wrong answer?", but then you say "I tried every testcase came to my mind. I didn't get wrong output.".  I'm confused.  Does your code work some of the time, all of the time, or none of the time?

Comment: For future commenters: This is the solution to a *programming contest* problem. That's why OP doesn't have access to the test cases that are failing. Basically, what he is asking is for you to construct a case that would break this code.

Comment: You better be *fast* - he's only got 3,000 seconds to solve it!

Comment: Thank you for the great information yzt. Would you please suggest some tricky test cases if you know any for this problem? Thanks.

Comment: @STLDeveloper Wrong Answer: I submitted the code and I got wrong answer. Wrong Output: I tried test cases but no wrong output found. So: I don't know for what kind of testcases it gets wrong answer.

Comment: I have the answer, but giving it would be unfair for the other participants.

Comment: @user2115614: Yes I do. It's in the **Answers** section.

Comment: @DanielDaranas How far is my code from yours? I mean the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code at least has two bugs.

#### Bug #1

This is the test case you are failing

```
989 1
0 0
```

Your code answers that there are 2 carry operations, while there is only one. And the problem (actually, one of the problems) is in these lines:

```
for(int i=index_a; i+1<v1.size(); i++)
for(int i=index_b; i+1<v2.size(); i++)
```

These should start from `index_a + 1` and `index_b + 1` and end with `i < v1.size()` and `i < v2.size()`.

#### Bug #2

And you *are not reading all the input*! Your main loop condition should be:

```
while (cin>>a>>b && (a!=0 || b!=0))
```

#### Test Case, Expected Output and Received Output

To be more clear, here's a test case:

```
989 1
1 989
11 0
0 11
2 3
2234 766
0 0
```

And here's the expected (correct) output:

```
1 carry operation.
1 carry operation.
No carry operation.
No carry operation.
No carry operation.
3 carry operations.
```

But your code gives this output (which is obviously wrong):

```
2 carry operations.
2 carry operations.
```

Comment: I fixed the code. Now it's giving the right output for testcases that you suggested. Still WA.

Answer (score 0):

What about this test-case:

```
5 5
11 0
99 999
0 0
```

?

Comment: 5 5: 1 carry operation. 11 0: exited the program 99 999: 3 carry operations. 0 0: exited the program

Comment: @user2115614: This is one of your problems. Your code does **not** read all the input! Basically, it gives up if even one of the numbers are zero. Read my answer above for a fix.

Comment: @ytz: Yes I see. I fixed that part but still having problem.

Comment: Also, should carry be reset to 0 before the first for loop?

Comment: @doctorlove That was the little tiny bug!! Got AC. Thanks.